# Why am I getting different answers for an integral depending on method?

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

I'm trying to carry out an integral and I'm finding different answers depending on which method I choose to integrate with. I assume this has something to do with divergent pieces but I don't understand what is happening and why I'm not receiving an error warning if there is a problem. Here is a test:

```
Block[{a = 0.2, b = 0.5}, 
  Integrate[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 π}]]
Block[{a = 0.2, b = 0.5}, 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 π}]] 
Integrate[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

This gives,

```
54.1654 + 0. I
-8.66648 + 8.40447*10^-16 I
0
```

#### Update

Corrected in *Mathematica* V10.3 (possibly earlier but this only version I have installed). -- m_goldberg

Comment: Thanks for the edit @belisarius. How did you do that?

Comment: [**By using this**](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/193):)

Comment: `a = 0.2; b = 0.5;
Plot[{Re@#, Im@#} &[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x])], {x, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, Evaluated -> True]`...branch cut ...

Comment: I am not seeing the 54.16.. result. I am using version 10.latest.

Comment: I also run the latest version (on ubuntu), and I do get the 54.16 result. @belisarius I don't see any branch cut. All the functions involved here do not have branch cuts, and the denominator can not vanish for $a,b\in$`Reals`.

Comment: OK I get $-8.67+1.07*10^{-14} I$, $-8.67 + 8.40*10^{-16} I$ and $0$, respectively. I'm on MMA 10.2 Win7-64.

Comment: Also, `Integrate[Exp[-I x]/(A + I B Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, B > 0}]` yields
$$\frac{2 \pi}{B}  \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}-2\right)$$

Comment: 10.1 gets the first two correct, still zero on the last.

Answer (score 1):

This must be considered a bug because V10.3 gives different and correct results.

```
Block[{a = 0.2, b = 0.5}, 
  Integrate[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 π}]]
```

> `-8.66646 + 1.06581*10^-14 I`

```
Block[{a = 0.2, b = 0.5}, 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 π}]]
```

> `-8.66646 + 1.06581*10^-14 I`

```
Assuming[0 < a < b, 
  Integrate[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2 π}]]
```

> `-((2 a π)/(a^2 b + b^3))`

```
With[{a = 0.2, b = 0.5}, -((2 a π)/(a^2 b + b^3))]
```

> `-8.66646`

Answer (score 0):

I am using MMA version 9.0.0.0 here.
The issue seems fixed by using exact fractions or Rationalize.
As an example:

```
rint = Rationalize@
    Block[{a = 0.2, b = 0.5},
        FullSimplify[Exp[-I x]/(a^2 - b^2 + 2 I a b Sin[x])]
    ];

Integrate[rint, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

> -((80 π)/29)

```
NIntegrate[rint, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

> -8.666475584+1.432009446*10^-16 I

```
Integrate[rint, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

> -((80 π)/29)

Without Rationalize, I get respectively:

> 0
>
> -8.666475584+1.432009446*10^-16 I
>
> 0

and the first and last are clearly wrong.